# How to use @Async correctly in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have a question about Spring's `@Async` annotation and how to correctly use it. Let's say I have these methods:

```
@Async
public void test(String param1) {
    test2(param1, null);
}

@Async
public void test2(String param1, String param2) {
    test3(param1, param2, null);
}

@Async
public void test3(String param1, String param2, String param3) {
    // do some heavy work
}
```

Do I need to have `@Async` on all three methods for it to be called asynchronously or is it enough only to have it on `test3` that will actually do the work?

Comment: Doesn't really have an answer to my question, just says the ``@Async`` block will be ran asynchronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need it only at one method. Just because, after a new thread is started with the first `@Async`-method, is is asynchronous to the invoking method.

But what this mean for you, is highly depending on what your example should illustrate:

**1)** So in your case, an `@Async` for `test1(String param1)` is enough when you ever invoke `test2` and `test3` through `test1`.

```
@Async
public void test1(String param1) {
    test2(param1, null);
}

private void test2(String param1, String param2) {
    test3(param1, param2, null);
}

private void test3(String param1, String param2, String param3) {
    // do something
}
```

*note that the methods 2 and 3 are private*

---

**2)** But if your example is for illustrating a method overloading pattern for default parameters ([Method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)), then it is more complicate. Then you would need to have the `@Async` annotation at the method that do the real stuff. Because you just want to execute the real execution in an async-way, but not one async invocation for each chaining step.

```
public void test(String param1) {
    test(param1, null);
}


public void test(String param1, String param2) {
    //this invocation runs async only when real AspectJ is used
    test(param1, param2, null);
}

@Async
public void test(String param1, String param2, String param3) {
    // do something
}
```

*note that all methods are named just `test` (method chaining pattern)*

**The problem with this is, that Spring (without real AspectJ load- or compile-time weaving) will not run a method async if it is invoked via `this`!** (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22561903/280244)

Comment: Yes, they are overloaded methods actually, don't know why I called them test1, test2 and test3 here... So basically, the method that does some async work (``test3`` in this case), must be public for it to actually be asynchronous (since I'm not using AspectJ)? Others shouldn't bother with the annotation?

Answer (score 2):

I think @Ralph covered your concerns.

But as the name of the question is "How to use @Async correctly in Spring", I have to mention this:

You should always change (or at least consider to change) default task executor in Spring context or use custom task executor.

[Because:](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html)

> By default, a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor will be used to process async
>   method invocations.

[and:](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html)

> **NOTE: This implementation does not reuse threads!** Consider a thread-pooling TaskExecutor implementation instead, in particular for
>   executing a large number of short-lived tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `@Async` only on the third method `test3` is not enough because calling locally cause that object is not proxied and only proxied objects (picked up from container, e.g. using `@Autowired`) has async calls

Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735455/spring-3-x-async-methods-not-called-concurrently-by-task-executor)